# firebase Retrieving only changes in JSON

Tags: json, flash, apache-flex, rest, firebase

I have a developer working on a Flash/Flex interface for an app that will communicate with Firebase. While there is no official library for Firebase or any kind of option really for this, the development is nearing completion based only on the REST API system. However, an interesting request has come to me from the developer so I thought I'd ask this community if this is possible.

When you have the firebase account open in your browser and a change to a node (or any child of a node) occurs, the interface highlights the change in one color or another. This is great for seeing how things are going.

However, since we are forced to use the REST API as json data, that data is not constantly "pushed" like it is with the javascript API, so in order to find changes in child nodes, we have to ping the JSON url for the top node and iterate down the changes to look for new nodes or changed nodes.

Ideally, it would be great if you could call a json url that ONLY shows you the changes since the timestamp provided. So for instance, if your url to firebase were mysite.firebaseio.com and the node you are inspecting is "application" then the normal url is https://mysite.firebaseio.com/application.json which yields the entire node with all children in a json string. What we would LIKE to be able to do is something like this: http://mysite.firebaseio.com/application.json?include=changes-since&since=1234567890 where the "include" is a variable that tells Firebase what to include and the value of "changes-since" tell Firebase to include only the changes (additions, modifications, deletions) since the "timestamp" variable value passed in.

This would DRAMATICALLY improve the performance of a REST API based application since it would not have to constantly loop and look for new, missing or changed objects.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This is currently not possible via the REST API, but we're working on providing some kind of real-time functionality over HTTP (watch the Firebase Google Group for announcements: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk).

Comment: Andrew, does your use case allow you to have ActionScript talk to JS and use the JS SDK? They can ferry real-time data back-and-forth in this manner. I think the same sort of ferrying can be done between Flex/Java.

Comment: Kato, unfortunately no. The Flex application we are building is intended to be added to an AdobeConnect meeting. We have no control over the AdobeConnect environment (html) that the meeting takes place in so we can't add any JS to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not as-yet seem to be any sort of flex-to-javascript library and it's been a few years since we created this. We did a lot of working around through our PHP server to essentially take the full data, filter it and return it to the Flex application. Since this question was posted, Firebase of course has developed new methods in the API, such as startAt, limitToLast, and even a streaming system, so most of my frustrations from 2013 are void, except that it would still be nice if there was a way to have Flash/Flex communicate directly. May not even be possible, but would be nice.